# What will be the alternative for repo sync command?

Tags: git, android-manifest, repo

I am new to git and I want to execute manifest file manually after doing `repo init`, instead of doing `repo sync`. To measure the time difference between normal git commands and `repo sync` in different cases. But I am not sure which git command to does repo uses.

I know that `repo` is just an wrapper for git for large codebase.

I just want to know what will be the exact command for `git clone` If I have the following Variables.

**- name
 - path
 - revision
 - upstream
 - remote**

I know how to form a url for git clone but not sure about revision and upstream.

Comment: Run  `repo --trace sync $name` and you will see what git commands get executed.

Comment: But I still isn't showing how git clone actually works for manifest file

Comment: It's approximately `git clone $remote -b $upstream -- $path && cd $path && git checkout $revision`. `repo init` and `repo sync` do much more than these commands.

Comment: I was looking for something like this. I know that repo provide much more functionalities but I wanted to try this manually.

Comment: And I wanted to know what is the significance of name

Comment: `remote` has an attribute `fetch` whose value is the url prefix of the server. The prefix and `name` form the actual url to the remote repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a sample manifest `default.xml`:

```
<manifest>
        <remote  name="aosp"
               fetch="https://android.googlesource.com/"/>
        <remote  name="test"
               fetch="https://github.com/test/"/>
        <default revision="master"
               remote="test"
               sync-j="4" />
        <project name="platform/tools/motodev" path="tools/motodev" revision="69989786cefbde82527960a1e100ec9afba46a98" upstream="master" remote="aosp"/>
</manifest>
```

Create a parent directory for testing

```
mkdir repotest
cd repotest
```

Create a git repository for the manifest

```
mkdir local_manifest
cd local_manifest
git init
# Create the default.xml file
git add default.xml
git commit -m "Local Manifest"
cd ..
```

[Download](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo) the `repo` tool

```
mkdir -p .bin
PATH="${HOME}/repotest/.bin:${PATH}"
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > .bin/repo
chmod a+rx .bin/repo
```

Init based on the local manifest

```
mkdir test
cd test
repo init -u ~/repotest/local_manifest/
```

Modify source code of `repo` to get more debugging output (in addition to `--trace` and `GIT_TRACE=1`)

```
nano .repo/repo/git_command.py
# Remove stderr argument from the subprocess.Popen call (line no: ~292)
# Also comment the line at line no: ~331 which includes the use of the above removed argument stderr
# Save the file and exit
```

Sync

```
export GIT_TRACE=1
repo --trace sync &> ../log
cd ..
```

Filter the log

```
grep "built-in:\|curl\|export" < log > temp
awk -F '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9]+ git.c:' '{print $1}' > trim1 < temp
awk -F 'trace: built-in:' '{print $2}' > trim2 < temp
paste -d' ' trim1 trim2 > filtered_log
```

Filtered Log shows the sequence of git commands being executed

```
  git version
  git describe HEAD
  git config --file /home/test/repotest/test/.repo/manifests.git/config --null --list
  git config --file /home/test/repotest/test/.repo/repo/.git/config --null --list
: export GIT_DIR=/home/test/repotest/test/.repo/manifests.git 
  git fetch origin --tags '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*' '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*' +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
  git upload-pack /home/test/repotest/local_manifest/
  git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs
  git gc --auto
  git symbolic-ref -m 'manifest set to refs/heads/master' refs/remotes/m/master refs/remotes/origin/master
: export GIT_DIR=/home/test/repotest/test/.repo/project-objects/platform/tools/motodev.git 
  git init
  git config --file /home/test/repotest/test/.repo/projects/tools/motodev.git/config --null --list
  git config --file /home/test/repotest/test/.repo/projects/tools/motodev.git/config --replace-all filter.lfs.smudge 'git-lfs smudge --skip -- %f'
  git config --file /home/test/repotest/test/.repo/projects/tools/motodev.git/config --replace-all filter.lfs.process 'git-lfs filter-process --skip'
  git config --file /home/test/repotest/test/.repo/projects/tools/motodev.git/config --unset-all core.bare
  git config --file /home/test/repotest/test/.repo/projects/tools/motodev.git/config --replace-all remote.aosp.url https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/motodev
  git config --file /home/test/repotest/test/.repo/projects/tools/motodev.git/config --replace-all remote.aosp.projectname platform/tools/motodev
  git config --file /home/test/repotest/test/.repo/projects/tools/motodev.git/config --replace-all remote.aosp.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/aosp/*'
curl --fail --output /home/test/repotest/test/.repo/projects/tools/motodev.git/clone.bundle.tmp --netrc --location https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/motodev/clone.bundle 
: export GIT_DIR=/home/test/repotest/test/.repo/projects/tools/motodev.git 
  git fetch /home/test/repotest/test/.repo/projects/tools/motodev.git/clone.bundle '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/aosp/*' '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
  git index-pack --fix-thin --stdin
  git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs
  git gc --auto
  git fetch aosp --tags '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*' '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/aosp/*' +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/aosp/master
  git fetch-pack --stateless-rpc --stdin --lock-pack --thin --no-progress https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/motodev/
  git unpack-objects -q --pack_header=2,2
  git rev-list --objects --stdin --not --all --quiet --alternate-refs
  git gc --auto
  git update-ref -m 'manifest set to 69989786cefbde82527960a1e100ec9afba46a98' --no-deref refs/remotes/m/master 69989786cefbde82527960a1e100ec9afba46a98^0
  git gc --auto
  git read-tree --reset -u -v HEAD
```

Now that's a lot of commands. (Observation: `repo` uses curl to download the repositories).

As suggested by User [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay), for the above manifest file, an approximation of git commands would be:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/motodev -b master -- tools/motodev 
cd tools/motodev
git checkout 69989786cefbde82527960a1e100ec9afba46a98
```

To compare the performance of the `repo` tool and git, you can do :

```
# For repo tool
repo --time sync
```

```
# For git commands
export GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1
git clone $remote -b $upstream -- $path 
cd $path 
git checkout $revision
```

or using [time](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) command to get the total execution time of the git commands

```
time -p sh -c 'git clone $remote -b $upstream -- $path ; cd $path ; git checkout $revision'
```

> **Note:** remote has an attribute fetch whose value is the url prefix of the server. The prefix and name form the actual url to the remote repository - User [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay)

More on the [Debugging Variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) used in git:

> **GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE**
>
> controls logging of performance data. The output
> shows how long each particular git invocation takes.
>
> **GIT_TRACE**
>
> controls general traces, which don’t fit into any specific category.
> This includes the expansion of aliases, and delegation to other
> sub-programs.