# Is "repo sync" equivalent to "git remote update && git rebase origin/branch"?

Tags: git, android-source, repo

In the [`repo sync`](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo#sync) documentation it is stated that:

```
If the project has been synchronized before, then repo sync is equivalent to:

git remote update
git rebase origin/branch

where branch is the currently checked-out branch in the local project directory. If the local branch isn't tracking a branch in the remote repository, then no synchronization occurs for the project.
```

This means that after I successfully `repo init && repo sync` once, then I can use

```
$ repo forall -c git update
$ repo forall -c git checkout -b $REPO_RREV $REPO_REMOTE/$REPO_RREV
$ repo forall -c git pull $REPO_REMOTE $REPO_RREV
```

in order to achieve the same outcome as `repo sync`.

I'm concerned about the following:

- If `repo` is a tool that manages multiple git repositories with the help of a *manifest.xml* file, what happens if the manifest changes in the remote repository(upstream)?
- If e.g. a new repository is added to the *manifest.xml* file, how is `repo sync` equivalent to `git remote update && git rebase origin/branch`?
- Isn't `repo sync` also updating the *manifest.xml* file and then pulling the newly added repository? Because if this is the case, then `repo sync` is clearly not equivalent to `repo forall -c git remote update && repo forall -c git rebase origin/branch`.

Is `repo sync` equivalent to `git remote update && git rebase origin/branch` or the documentation is missing something? Can someone please clarify how `repo sync` really works under the hood from this point of view?

Comment: @matt But I run `repo forall -c git remote update` inside the directory where the `.repo` folder is. In that directory there is no `.git` folder thus no git repository. So how can I `git remote update` all repositories if I don't use `repo forall`?

Comment: Run `repo --trace sync` and you will see the git commands.

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59463893/10155936) with the help of @ElpieKay

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on what I understood from the [doc link](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo#sync) you mention in your question :

- `repo sync` is not executed on the sub projects, so will not be impacted by changes to their `manifest.xml` if they have one ;
- the doc has several "If"s ; the one before your quote states :

> - If the project has never been synchronized, then `repo sync` is equivalent to `git clone`. All branches in the remote repository are copied to the local project directory.

- `repo sync` updates the projects listed in this manifest, not the root project itself, so your root `manifest.xml` file is not modified by this command.

---

If you want to emulate `repo sync` with a `repo forall ...`, you would indeed need to take into account the actions for a new repo : `git clone`, and possibly some other commands.

Check the output of `repo --trace sync` as @ElpieKay suggested.